# Queryspec ItemCollection pagination dynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

This is my code

```
QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec()
        .withKeyConditionExpression(CONSTANT_DYNAMO_KEY_EXPRESSION)
        .withNameMap(map)
        .withValueMap(
            new ValueMap().withString(CONSTANT_DYNAMO_TARGET_TENANT_TYPE, targetTenantType))
        .withProjectionExpression(CONSTANT_DYNAMO_KEY_TENANT_ID);

// Execute the query
ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.getIndex(CONSTANT_DYNAMO_INDEX).query(querySpec);

Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator(); 

while (iterator != null & iterator.hasNext()) 
{
    Item item = iterator.next(); 
    String tenantName = item.getString("str_1");
    System.out.println(tenantName);
}
```

Is the pagination already implemented here, or do I need to add manual code?

I tried this but I don't know if I need to code to fetch all the pages from DynamoDB

Answer (score 0):

The iterator will automatically paginate for you when it calls the `next()` method.